# Internet Explorer won't load site

Tags: ssl, https, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer (versions 6 and 8, on XP) refuse to load https://theveeb.com, giving a server not found error.

http://wiki.theveeb.com works, so it can talk to the apache2 server I have running there.

The only thing I can think of is that IE is hating my SSL setup... but I can't think of why that would be or what I need to do to fix it.

When I try http://theveeb.com in the same browsers, I get the same effect.  They should redirect to https://, but they don't seem to, they just error.

Firefox, Uzbl, curl, wget on Ubunt work fine
wget.exe on Windows seems to also work fine

Comment: You really didn't provide enough information for anyone to help here.  Remember that we don't know your project and when you ask your question you need to start at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the issue.  When you have  SSLVerifyClient optional  in your config file, IE completely fails to load the page.  Wow.

Comment: We just ran into the same problem. Took many days to track down. We could only reproduce the problem on IE8, and then, only with all the tls options enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have  MIME type problem. When I go to http://theveeb.com in IE8, it prompts me to download your HTML.

Comment: That's good! If you're getting a MIME error that means IE has found the site, which it would not for me or the other person I had test it.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong, but theveeb.com and wiki.theveeb.com both resolve to the same ip address so shouldn't one or both of them be configured with host headers? If wiki.theveeb.com works then I'm assuming that it's the default web site on the server and that theveeb.com site should be configured with host headers. Am I wrong?

Comment: apache2 switches between sites based on the Host header sent by the browser, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
user@lap:~$ curl hXXp://theveeb.com/ -IL
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2009 22:23:45 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: hXXps://theveeb.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2009 22:23:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8

your page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "hXXp://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="hXXp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="theveeb">
....



user@lap:~$ curl hXXps://theveeb.com/ -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2009 22:24:40 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny3
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Accept
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Yes, curl wget both worked on windows, it was just IE having the problem.

Comment: I included full headers to show that you got wrong Content-Type and xml definition instead of html/xhtml - that can be a problem because IE has out content type detection (MIME sniffing , FindMIMEFromData-funktion - see MSDN). Remove the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> and look if it works then.

Comment: which error you get? If "The XML page cannot be displayed" its a MIME problem.

Comment: No, as I said, I was getting a server not found error.  It didn't get far enough to know anything about MIME types.  (Yes, I tried changing the MIME type just in case... that didn't fix anything)